# geckodriver Firefox c# FindElement and SendKeys too slow always

Tags: c#, performance, selenium, geckodriver

I have created six automation tests with Selenium in `C#` with `Visual Studio 2017` to test a web site with `Firefox`. 
I have tried using several versions of `Selenium`. `FireFox.WebDriver`

```
0.20.0  

0.20.1

0.21.0
```

Which all install `geckodriver`.

I am using both `Selenium.WebDriver` and `Selenium.Support` version `3.13.0`.

They all work perfectly.

The only problem is that the `FindElement` and `SendKeys` are always too slow for each and every input field of all web pages I want to test, even if they contain only few characters.

So I have tried to use `ChromeDriver` and it is much faster compared to `geckodriver`.
But we need to test with `FireFox`, not with `Chrome`.

This is my `code` which works but is too slow:

```
IWebDriver driver;
driver = new FirefoxDriver("./");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/");                
driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtUserName")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtUserName")).SendKeys(userId);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtPassword")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtPassword")).SendKeys(password);
```

I have tried and removed the `Clear()` statement and the code still works, but the slowness persists.

Can you please suggest?

Comment: How much slow is it ? IMO it's fine .Check with your team whether they want to use headless browser which is much faster.

Comment: How much time does the test take? How much time would you like it to take? Which version of Firefox? Firefox is no speed demon, which is why Mozilla created [Firefox Quantum](https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2017/11/14/introducing-firefox-quantum/).

Comment: I am using Firefox Quantum 61.0 (64-bit).
It takes between 4 and 8 seconds between populating one input box and the next one: 
4 seconds for a simple input box and 8 seconds for selecting a value in a list box.